# Is the Repository Pattern needed with Prisma if you have a service layer?

Tags: typescript, architecture, repository

Because Prisma is kind of like an ORM it already gives you great tools for accessing data in the database is a Repository pattern needed.. I have read conflicting opinions and basically it seems to be "it depends.. maybe... maybe not" which is not helpful.

So given the following:

```
export class AvatarPartRepo extends BaseRepo<"avatar_part"> {
  getAllForUser(owningUserId: string): Promise<avatar_part[]> {
    return this.model.findMany({ where: { owningUserId } });
  }

  findOneForUser({
    owningUserId,
    definitionId,
  }: {
    definitionId: string;
    owningUserId: UUID;
  }): Promise<avatar_part | null> {
    return this.model.findFirst({ where: { definitionId, owningUserId } });
  }

  doesUserHave({
    owningUserId,
    definitionId,
  }: {
    definitionId: AvatarPartDefinitionIds;
    owningUserId: UUID;
  }): Promise<boolean> {
    return this.findOneForUser({ definitionId, owningUserId }).then((o) => o != undefined);
  }

  getDefinitionIdsForUser(owningUserId: string): Promise<string[]> {
    return this.model
      .findMany({ where: { owningUserId }, select: { definitionId: true } })
      .then((r) => r.map((x) => x.definitionId));
  }

  create(input: {
    owningUserId: UUID;
    definitionId: AvatarPartDefinitionIds | string;
  }): Promise<avatar_part> {
    return this.model.create({ data: input });
  }
}
```

Should this Repository even exist? or should it live in a "Service Layer"?

The problem is if I end up having both a service layer AND repository I end up "forwarding" a bunch of things to the repository  in the service layer which makes it feel a bit redundant.

```
export class AvatarPartsService extends BaseService {

  getAllForUser = this.repos.avatarParts.getAllForUser.bind(this.repos.avatarParts);

  doesUserHave = this.repos.avatarParts.doesUserHave.bind(this.repos.avatarParts);

  create = this.repos.avatarParts.createPart.bind(this.repos.avatarParts);

  findOneForUser = this.repos.avatarParts.findOneForUser.bind(this.repos.avatarParts);

}
```

The service layer only really exists because the "view" layer shouldnt directly talk to the repositories as far as I understand it?

And if the answer is "no this shouldnt exist" then should ANY repo exist if you are using Prisma?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it can be good in terms of separation of concerns.
Service layer - business logic, repository layer - data access logic.
Imagine scenario when your user can't upload avatar if he is registered for less than 1 day. 
In this case, your code can look like this:

```js
class AvatarPartsService {
  create(userId) {
    const timeElapsedSinceUserRegistration = await this.getTimeSinceUserRegistration(userId);
    if (timeElapsedSinceUserRegistration < 3600) throw new NotMatureUserError();
    
    this.avatarPartsRepo.create(); 
  }
}
```

If replace `this.avatarPartsRepo.create()` code with `this.prisma.avatarParts.create` in the example above we can encounter next situation.

We have an admin role (and "AdminsService"). And he has the functionality to create avatar for any user not depending on when it was registered.

In this case, we can't use `AvatarPartsService.create` as it won't create an avatar for 'too young' users. 
So we have to repeatedly write `this.prisma.avatarParts.create` or just reuse our `this.avatarPartsRepo.create`.

Comment: Yes I find this is true for "mutation" type functionality, the service layer is definately needed to provide your business constraints. But for 99.9% of data "queries" then I havent seen a need. Thoughts?

Comment: I think repositories are just a way to be ready for some kind of probable changes in your application. 
Personally I, in my project, have repositories (even having prisma) and in some cases I replace Prisma.DbNull/Prisma.JsonNull values with simply ```null``` to make things more comfortable to me. Of course, I can do the same logic just in services, but it'll bloat it.

Also there is place where I want to ensure that value I save to DB follows email format. Yes, I do validation in controller. But double-check it in repository - I suppose it's also nice.